# Javascript - Prevent Child's OnClick Firing Parent's OnClick - Without JQuery

Tags: javascript, dom

I have two elements, like this:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("el");
var child = parent.children[0];
```

and then a eventListener:

```
parent.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("Hello World!")
});
```

and the problem is that when you click the child, the parents click event will be fired.

I want only when you click on the parent to fire the alert, not when you click on the child.

I am not using JQuery and won't.

I have searched on google, and all results uses e.stopPropogation which is JQuery.

So what's the best way to do this in plain JS?

Thanks alot.

Comment: *"I have searched on google, and all results uses e.stopPropogation which is JQuery."* Nope, `stopPropagation` is native: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation

Comment: It's the W3C standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-event-type-stopPropagation. Browser support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation#Browser_Compatibility. If you need to support IE8 and below you have to assign `e.cancelBubble = true;`.

Comment: Just delete it. It's about nothing at all, my bad.

Comment: If you change your mind about jQuery, they have something to handle this specifically. jQuery event namespaces http://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/

Comment: @BenRecord No way never gonna use JQ

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent event bubbling up to the parent element. For this you have to bind one more event handler to the child element:

```
child.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Click event bubbles which means that event travels up DOM tree from child to parent unless its propagation is stopped.

Comment: Yes, my mistake for posting the jquery URL at w3schools. This is what I was reading - http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-events

Answer (score 0):

You can check the ID of the clicked element and use that to control the trigger:

http://jsfiddle.net/nccjgtp6/

```
<div id="el">
    This is a thing.
    <div id="el2"> This is a second thing. </div>
</div>

var parent = document.getElementById("el");
var child = parent.children[0];

parent.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    if(e.srcElement.id == 'el') {
        alert('Hello world');
    }
});
```

I do not know if this will work consistently in all browsers, but works for me in Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, it's the `event.stopPropagation();` line of code you need.

Comment: At Murply x: that was more than unnecessary.


At bob: you were down-voted purely because it was posted as a solution, and should have been a comment. You're fine.